# How can I dynamically assign variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, dictionary

I have a c# test that uses selenium web driver to test a web page. I have a large number of element names and xpath locations stored in a text file (so that others without access to the code can make updates when the xpath to an element changes), which is read into a dictionary using an array and File.ReadAllLines, so it looks something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)) 
{
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) &&
    (!line.StartsWith(";")) &&
    (!line.StartsWith("#")) &&
    (!line.StartsWith("'")) &&
    (line.Contains("=")))
{
    int index = line.IndexOf("=");
    string key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();
    string value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();

    if ((value.StartsWith("\"") && value.EndsWith("\"")) ||
        (value.StartsWith("'") && value.EndsWith("'")))
    {
        value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
    }

    dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

I then define a variable, and assign the value of the matching key's value to the variable.
But different releases of our page have different xpath values for the same elements, so I want to version the information in the text file, and dynamically assign the variable in the script to match the version #, so the same code can test multiple versions.
For example:
I have a variable string version = "v2.3" or "v2.4" depending on which version I am testing against.
One of the keys from the dictionary is v2.3_usernamefield, value = some xpath
Another is v2.4_usernamefield, value = a different xpath from v2.3

I'd like to be able to prepend the version variable to a root variable name, so that I could set the variable for webdriver to look for to be version specific - something like:
              driver.findelement(By.Xpath(version+usernamefield))

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have to keep versioning inside of the text file? I think a better approach would be to tie the file to the product version/branch/release, so that each version has it's set of values. I feel this would be much simpler to manage. I also think that a custom section, correctly typed, would be a bit better in the long run, but I'm not entirely sure if you can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do what a `Dictionary` is there for you to do. You don't need to create dynamic variables. You just need to create dynamic keys and access them if you want.

If you only had one set of keys to access, then a `Dictionary<string, object>` would have sufficed. For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object() 
    { 
        {"UserName", "John"} , 
        {"OtherAttribute", "Value"} 
    };
```

If you now have a version you want to prepend, you can either add that to the previous dictionary like so:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object() 
     { 
         {"v2.3_UserName", "John"}, 
         {"c2.4_UserName", "Kale"} 
     };
```

Or you can create a dict inside another dict:

```
var versionDictThenKeyValueDict = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>()
        { 
            {"v2.3", new Dictionary<string, object> { {"UserName", "John"} } 
        };
```

Comment: OK, helps, thanks.  I think I was over-complicating it by trying to have the out variable be dynamic too, but your example made me realize I don't need to do that.  I can have the same variable for either version.  Thanks!